# Gridview Displays Empty, but search brings up the data in gridview

Tags: gridview

I'm performing a search in GridView. Thing is when I bring up the default page it displays no data, when there really is data. But when I perform the search function it brings up the data. I'm using Filter expression to search for a record in the Gridview by the First Name column. And when I take out the FilterExpression bit it displays fine, but when I add it back it displays nothing, but search still works.

```
< asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:SDAppDBsConnectionString2 %>"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE PatInfo SET FirstName = @FirstName,
      LastName = @LastName, MiddleInitial = @MiddleInitial, HomeAddress = @HomeAddress,
      PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber, Gender = @Gender, DOB = @DOB, SSN = @SSN WHERE (ID = @ID)"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM PatInfo WHERE (ID = @ID)"
    SelectCommand="select * from [PatInfo]"
    FilterExpression="FirstName LIKE '%{0}%'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Did ya try run the query on your database manager? sqlserver? Just to see if that brings back any results with the filter? Just to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Yeah I was researching more on this and checked the DataSource Select statement Queried it in the Query Builder and it's not displaying anything as well. Strange I don't get it. It only displays the data after I enter some key words then it brings the data up. I'd like for the data to already be displayed before I perform the search. :/ If I figure something out I'll make sure to post my solution. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Still nothing I think I tried just about everything. Anyone have any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!!! I had text already populated into the textbox once the page loads. When the User clicks the Text box to search it automatically highlights all the text for the user to search. Here's the example.

```
 Original---> <asp:TextBox ID="SearchPatientBox"
  runat="server">Search for a Patient</asp:TextBox>

 Changed----> <asp:TextBox ID="SearchPatientBox"
  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I'm assuming the search function was implementing already via the Page loading and displayed an empty Gridview because "Search for a Patient" was no where in the GridView First Name or Last Name database Columns. *Smacks Head* Something so simple.....

Crazy, but glad I finally figured it out and thank you for trying to help once again.